# Importancia del manejo de archivos

Tags: python, archivo, archivo-de-propiedades

Aprendiendo a programar en Python, me he encontrado con el tema de manejo o manipulación de archivos, y veo que es importante en el mundo de programación, ya que siempre se enseña en todo lenguaje.
Sin embargo, he tratado de buscar por qué es tan importante, pero sólo encuentro tutoriales sobre cómo abrir archivo, leer archivo, cerrar archivo, etc. Debido a esto, tengo algunas preguntas en las que espero me puedan ayudar:

1. ¿Cuál es su importancia?
2. ¿Cómo puedo aplicarlo en un proyecto real?
3. Sé que puedo abrir, modificar y cerrar un texto internamente, pero ¿no sería lo mismo hacerlo desde el bloc de notas? (puede parecer estúpida esta pregunta, pero realmente tengo esta duda).

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

Comment: La pregunta se presta a opiniones, por lo que te voy a decir es a título de opinión. La importancia del manejo de ficheros es **FUNDAMENTAL**. Piensa que utilizamos los ordenadores para hacer cosas de forma más rápida que un ser humano pudiese hacer. SI te piden extraer en un fichero CSV los datos de una base de datos para que los estudie el departamente de marketing, efectivamente puedes hacerlo escribiendolo en el block de notas, ¿pero cuánto tardarías? Lo que tu tardarías horas o días en hacer, un ordenador te lo hace en pocos segundos.

Comment: Utilizamos la programación para realizar tareas. Se tarda en programar, pero una vez hecho el programa, podemos ejecutarlo muchas veces y hacer tareas costosas y repetitivas de forma muy rápida.

Comment: La manipulación de archivos es como su nombre lo dice ```manipular```, supongamos que tienes un fichero CSV con muchas columnas y filas con datos como nombres,apellidos,tarjetas de credito,deudas, direcciones y tu jefe necesita que tu extraigas solo los datos de las personas que tenga una deuda con un valor determinado , eso lo podrias hacer en python e incluso insertarlo en una base de datos con pocas lineas de código. Otro ejemplo, tienes un fichero ```XML``` lo cual viaja como representacion de datos, se transforma en un objeto para poder trabajar como objeto.

Comment: Entonces, me queda claro que me permite ahorrar tiempo y ser más práctico, por ende, ser mucho más eficiente con el manejo de datos. Muchas gracias a ambos!

Answer (score 1):

El manejo de archivos es importante saberlo porque se puede aplicar en muchas áreas, por ejemplo, puedes escribir los logs de su sistema, para saber como se comporta sus sitema en producción, algunos prefieren hacer ésto con una DB, pero un archivo será menos costoso. Para extraer información de una DB y convertirla en csv, para hacer pequeños scripts que se creen en ejecución y hagan otra cosa, en linux podría hacer scripts .bash que se creen automáticamente para después ejecutarlos. Para automatizar documentación de sistemas, para crear páginas web estilo drag and drop, para ello va escribiendo en un archivo html, lo que va arrastrando, y mucho más.